Angular router.navigate is not changing url, but only on first load
In my component I have something which is basically:
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._user.session$.subscribe((session: UserSession | null) => {
        if (session?.appKey) {
            // trying this as it was recommended on other posts
            this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    
            this._router.navigate([this._returnUrl]).then(() => {
                if (this._router.url !== this._returnUrl)) {
                    // this should never happen
                    // only happens on first loading of app
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    })
}

On the first load, the this._router.navigate acts like it worked, but does not navigate away. If I reload, it will work - any idea what I can do so I don't have to do a manual reload?
angular/router 13.3.11

Do you have stackblitz url to reproduce this issue ? What is the first load URL when the issue is happening?
check for any navigation errors as well. you can find detailed steps of the navigation by enabling the tracing of routes like below
RouterModule.forRoot(
routes,
{ enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
)

It was a guard intercepting the call and re-routing.

You can use routerReuseStrategy which recreates the route when we have the property reloadSamePath set as true in the data property of the current route.
First add the property on the route.
export const routes = [
  {
    path: 'test/:id',
    component: ChildComponent,
    data: { reloadSamePath: true },
  },
];

Then in the reuse strategy, check if same route and return true to reload!
  shouldReuseRoute(
    future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    if (future?.data?.['reloadSamePath'] && curr?.data?.['reloadSamePath']) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

RouteReuseStrategy
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  DetachedRouteHandle,
  RouteReuseStrategy,
} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  /**
   * Whether the given route should detach for later reuse.
   * Always returns false for `BaseRouteReuseStrategy`.
   * */
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * A no-op; the route is never stored since this strategy never detaches routes for later re-use.
   */
  store(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle
  ): void {}

  /** Returns `false`, meaning the route (and its subtree) is never reattached */
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  /** Returns `null` because this strategy does not store routes for later re-use. */
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Determines if a route should be reused.
   * This strategy returns `true` when the future route config and current route config are
   * identical.
   */
  shouldReuseRoute(
    future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    if (future?.data?.['reloadSamePath'] && curr?.data?.['reloadSamePath']) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  provideRouter,
  RouterModule,
  Router,
  RouteReuseStrategy,
} from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { CustomReuseStrategy } from './router-reuse-strategy';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('reloading');
  }
}

export const routes = [
  {
    path: 'test/:id',
    component: ChildComponent,
    data: { reloadSamePath: true },
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
  <a (click)="navigateToSomeRoute()">some route</a>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigateToSomeRoute() {
    this.router.navigate(['test', `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100)}`]);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy },
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo

public ngOnInit(): void {
this._user.session$.subscribe((session: UserSession | null) => {
    if (session?.appKey) {
        // Debugging: Log the session and returnUrl
        console.log('Session:', session);
        console.log('Return URL:', this._returnUrl);

        // Ensure this._returnUrl is set correctly
        if (this._returnUrl) {
            this._router.navigate([this._returnUrl]).then((navigated: boolean) => {
                // Debugging: Log the result of the navigation
                console.log('Navigation result:', navigated);
                console.log('Current URL:', this._router.url);

                if (!navigated || this._router.url !== this._returnUrl) {
                    // This should never happen
                    // Only happens on first loading of app
                    console.warn('Navigation failed, reloading window');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Navigation error:', error);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Return URL is not set');
        }
    }
});

}

Please explain why your snippet solves the problem
